# Create a Windows executable that does not create a console window

Tags: windows, haskell, ghc, windows-console

I compiled a Windows GUI application with `haskell-gi`. Everything seems to be working fine. However, every time I double click on the executable in Windows Explorer to execute the program, Windows also creates a console window (i.e. a terminal) along with the main window of my application. Is it possible to ask Windows to not create the console window, which is how typical Windows GUI apps behave?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [ghc user guide](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/win32-dlls.html?#interacting-with-the-terminal), you can build a GUI-only application by adding the `-optl-mwindows` flag to your build.
Notice the warning in the link that says that in this mode using standard IO functions (`putStrLn`, `getLine`, or anything that reads from stdin or writes to stdout/stderr) will fail with an `IOException` on Windows.